# Signalr Core Adding user to Groups OnConnected Security

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I've seen one article that said groups were bad to use if you needed anything to be secure, but I'm wondering if that is still true or how someone would take advantage of this scenario:

Say I had one company with multiple subdivisions.  I want to send notifications only to a particular subdivision when an action happens.  Even though it's odd, say in this scenario that it would be bad security wise if a different subdivision saw the notification.

The client hub does not have any "send" methods on it so it looks like this:

```cs
[Authorize]
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{

}
```

I then have a service class on the api that uses the IHubContext to send a notification to the group

```cs
public class NotificationService : INotificationService{
    public async Task UpdateScheduleAsync(string subdivision, string message)
    {
         await _hubContext.Clients.Group(subdivision).SendAsync("ReceiveMessage",message);
    }
}
```

If I added in the NotificationsHub the method:

```cs
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
   //may or may not use the identifier
   var someUserIdentityInfo = Context.UserIdentifier; 

   //would grab the subdivision the authorized user is apart of
   var subdivision = GrabSubdivisonFromIdentity(someUserIdentityInfo);

   //add to the subdivison group
   foreach(var division in subdivison){
     await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, division);
   }

   await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

Is there any way for a person to connect to the group if they know the other division names? Is this still a bad idea?

I'm trying to avoid keeping a list of "logged in" users and sending out the change by user individually one by one for each change.

Comment: The security issue with signalr groups was during the reconnection. Signalr core doesn't automatically reconnect. When a connection drops you'll have to reconnect the client and go through the OnConnectedAsync where the groups are set based on user identity. So I think it's not possible with your code for a user to join a group he is not meant to. I'm not sure if the reconnect was the only source of security issue, so I'll let someone else give an answer.

Comment: Division/department/team names change over time, don't rely on those values. I handle that same scenario today by having a table with "department" and a "department_group" fields. Rather than using the name of the department/division, generate a unique id string for each. You can send updates/changes like normal to the group. On connect, you need just need to add the users in Division A to group "unique_id_1" and users in Division B to group "unique_id_x" and so on. It already sounds like you have a method to determine what Division a user belongs to.